# What hardware setup is required to use MPI with CUDA?

Tags: cuda, mpi

I am new to MPI. I want use CUDA with MPI.   I am having three PCs, each having one GPU,  which I want to use for doing some simple processing (matrix multiplication).

But I am not sure what hardware setup is required to use MPI with CUDA?
Please enlighten me.

**Update**
I am asking this as many a place mentions clusters with infiniband. I do not have such a set up. I only have ordinary Lan that we have in offices. 
 And above all the basic idea is to have a feel of how MPI and CUDA work together and do small small tests runs--irrespective of the performance.

Answer (score 2):

One or more machines with nVidia GPUs that are capable of CUDA.

MPI and CUDA don't have anything to do with each other. You simply use CUDA within each MPI process.

Comment: so you mean If I connect my Pcs having graphics cards, in ordinary lan, that we have in offices ---it will work ? I dont need to have infiniband and stuffs like that?  right?

Comment: Sure, you can use ordinary ethernet. MPICH and OpenMPI will both work with whatever your OS supports. Note that matrix multiplication is a tightly-coupled problem and is very bandwidth intensive. So it will be slow over a slow interconnect like GbE.

Comment: @gpuguy A lot of academic clusters are simply a bunch of PCs connected to a switch. The only reason you hear about Infiniband or Gemini or Myrinet interconnects is because they're faster. For many classes of problems the speed of the interconnect is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

But, but way of a followup to the OP's original question, if I may?

I realize that @gpuguy's Q was about *hardware*, but isn't it true that he must be running one of the OS options the Nvidia CUDA compilers supports? (IE, Linux, Win, OSX)

There is no OpenSource equivalent of CUDA, is there?